# Shell script to increment hour in date-time

Tags: shell, date, datetime

Can anyone help me to add only the hour part in below date/time format:

For instance, starting with 20 August 10:00am

```
2016-08-20-10
```

I would like to increment only the hour part, so that I get:

```
2016-08-20-11
2016-08-20-12
2016-08-20-13
etc.
```

stopping at a specified date, such as 2016-08-21-08

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: Why does this need to be done recursively?  A simple iterative loop should do the job for you.

Comment: I meant to say iteration but my brain thought recursive. Thanks for the corrections

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution to my own question. See below:

```
date=(2016-08-23-0 2016-08-23-1 2016-08-23-2 2016-08-24-0 2016-08-24-1 2016-08-24-2)
date_arr=(2016-08-23-2 2016-08-24-2)

for ((i=0; i<"${#date[@]}"; i++))
   do
       if [[ " ${date_arr[*]} " == *"${date[i]}"* ]]
         then
            for ((j=0; j<=3; j++))
            do
                    echo "${date[i]}$j"
            done
       else
            for ((k=0; k<=9; k++))
            do
                    echo "${date[i]}$k"
            done
       fi
   done
```